# isRetinaScaling is not a function Fabricjs?

Tags: jquery, css, web, fabricjs

In fabricjs 1.6 shows `isRetinaScaling is not a function` error for some effects? This is happens when I trying to add a shadow effect as below. How to solve this?

```
$('#text-shadow-set').change(function (){
if(isText()) {
    if(this.checked) {
        var tmp = $('#text-shadow-offset-slider').slider('option','value');
        var shadVal = (tmp==''||tmp==0) ? 20 : tmp;
        this.setShadow({
            color: '#000',
            blur: 5,
            offsetX: shadVal,
            offsetY: shadVal
        });
        canvas.renderAll();
    } else {
        alert();
        this.setShadow(null);
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: please show code. There is no isRetinaScaling  in all fabricjs. Where did you take the library from?

Comment: http://www.deltalink.it/andreab/fabric/fabric.js  if you took this, this is my personal experimental version. do not thrust it.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi  This is happens when I trying to add a shadow effect. Code has been added.

Comment: Where di you take the build from?

Comment: The shadow effect applies to the jQuery DOM object and not to the Fabric canvas object. The "this" refers to $('#text-shadow-set').